# Proguard Issue using Sinch Library

Tags: android, sinch

I am using Sinch Library for voice calling.

While Enabling proguard I am getting this error

`Warning:com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.fcm.InstanceIDTokenService: can't find referenced method 'android.content.ComponentName startService(android.content.Intent)' in program class com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.fcm.InstanceIDTokenService`

This is my proguard file :

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.**

-keep class com.sinch.** { *; }
-keep interface com.sinch.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
-keep class com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.fcm.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.android.gms.**{ *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn android.media.**
```

Comment: sinch website mentions that - they have included one sample proguard file . Have you taken steps mentioned in that. Refer [link][1]


  [1]: https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#runningproguard

Comment: Yes . I already added that thing in my proguard. There is no clear link to proguard. In sdk they have specified in sample. so I have used that